# post creates document but data not sent

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

sending form data to mongodb with mongoose and express - the document is created with an id but the form data does not get sent

the schema

```
const reportSchema = mongoose.Schema({
      project: [
        {
        studio: String,
        code: String,
        name: String
        }
      ],
      },
    {
      collection: 'reports'
    }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Report', reportSchema);
```

and the route

```
app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  const report = new Report({
    project: {
      studio: req.body.studio,
      code: req.body.code,
      name: req.body.name
    }
  });
  report.save(err => {
    if (err) return res.status(404).send({ message: err.message });

    return res.send({ report });
  });
```

sending a post request in postman creates a document with an empty array.

The post looks like

```
{
    "project": {
        "studio": "main",
        "code": "411",
        "name": "some project"
    }
}
```

thanks for any help

[image]

updating the route to

```
app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  const report = new Report({
    project: {
      studio: req.body.project.studio,
      code: req.body.project.code,
      name: req.body.project.name
    }
  });
```

Returns an undefined error

[image]

Comment: Can you show what you sent in postman?

Comment: Please check my answer.

Comment: updated to include project @CuongLeNgoc returns an 'undefined error"

Comment: Can you show the full screenshot of postman request?

Comment: the header is set to content-type application/json - still get the undefined error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197866/discussion-between-cuong-le-ngoc-and-gosmith).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sent an object with `project` field in the `req.body` so you need to get it in this way:

```
const report = new Report({
  project: {
    studio: req.body.project.studio,
    code: req.body.project.code,
    name: req.body.project.name
  }
});
```

If it still doen't work, maybe the `Content-Type` of your request is not `application/json`. Try adding it to the request header.

**Note:** Make sure you have body-parser in your app.